# Why was Monica Geller overweight in her younger years?

Tags: analysis, friends

[Monica Geller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monica_Geller) was shown as overweight in her early or college days in [Friends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends).
In all seasons she was shown as normal weight.

- Why was Monica Geller overweight in her early years?
- How did she become normal weight?

Comment: Because it makes for an interesting plot?

Comment: She lost weight by working out a lot.
There is an episode where phoebe and her sees Monicas old room, and there are a lot of exercising machines in there.
Also that is why Monica is so strong, because she works out a lot.

Comment: You either jest or you somehow missed the fact that her dad converted her room into a gym for himself *after* she moved out... She simply stopped eating a lot. As she said about her former self, "I never let her eat".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Monica was fat in her younger years because she ate too much.**

- In [The One Where Rachel Tells...](http://www.friends-tv.org/zz803.html) Ross says:

  > *I grew up with Monica. If you didn't eat fast, you didn't eat!*
- In  [The One With The Pediatrician](http://www.friends-tv.org/zz903.html) we learn that Ross used to go to a therapist, because

  > **Monica:** ... *he used to have this recurring nightmare. It really freaked him out.*
  >   
  > **Rachel:** *Wow, what was it?*
  > **Monica:** *That I was going to eat him.*
- In  [The One With Phoebe's Cookies](http://www.friends-tv.org/zz703.html) it is revealed that Monica was once sent to *fat camp*:

  > **Ross:** *He still tells the story about how Monica tried to escape from fat camp.*
  >   
  > **Monica:** *I wasn't escaping!*
  >   
  > **Ross:** *Then how did you get caught in the barbed wire?*
  >   
  > **Monica:** *I was trying to help out a squirrel.*
  >   
  > **Ross:** *You were trying to eat it!*

**Monica lost the weight because of an incident during [Thanksgiving 1987](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_One_with_All_the_Thanksgivings),** when she overhears Chandler say to Ross:

> *I just don't want to be stuck here all night with your fat sister.*

- [[Watch the scene on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFskf5fQYgI#t=4m22s)]

  [image: 1987]

That prompted Monica to lose weight, which she successfully managed by Thanksgiving 1988.

- [[Watch the scene on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0-1vwCn-WM#t=0m32s)]

  [image: 1988]

Comment: On the back of this, it provides some background to her character. Provides a little information about 4 of the characters via flashbacks and serves to make her a more three dimensional character. She has a character trait, struggles with it and over comes it.