# How did Monica Geller maintain her "skinny" weight after losing all that weight?

Tags: friends

Monica in *Friends* lost around 110 lbs but I don't know how she maintained her weight after that. We have seen her working out in season 1 and 2 and that's only.

Comment: Is it really so farfetched that people can maintain a diet?

Comment: I don't think that only diet can melt so much weight (especially fat).

Comment: Losing weight is harder than maintain it, is it quite easy to maintain weight you know what you are doing.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. She went on a diet and maintained that weight loss. The show doesn't make a fuss over it, Monica just says at some point that she eats in moderation.

Comment: Is this really a TV question or one about how to lose weight?

Comment: I don't ask how can I lose weight or something... I don't need that anyway.It's just interesting how she did it.

Answer (score 7):

- Her primary motivation (ironically) was Chandler's [hurtful comment about her weight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8886/why-was-monica-geller-overweight-in-her-younger-years?rq=1).

> **Monica:** *What?! I mean, I didn't work this hard and-and-and lose all this weight so that I can give my flower to someone like him!*

- She goes to the gym / jogs daily.

> **Joey:** *Hey Mon, I got a question for you.*
>
> **Monica:** *Okay, for the bizillionth time, yes I see other women in the shower at the gym, and no I don't look.*

- She mainly drinks diet soda

> **Chandler:** *Yeah, can I get a 3-piece, some coleslaw, some beans, and a Coke—[Monica grabs him underwater] **Diet** Coke.*

- Her trigger food (for gaining weight) was apparently Brown Bird cookies.

> **Monica:** *All right, I’ll take one box of the mint treasures, just one, and that’s it. I-I started gaining weight after I joined the Brown Birds. Remember, how Dad bought all my boxes and I ate them all?*

- Although she seems ok with other cookies (and food in general) Monica has an almost pathological fear of Brown Bird cookies.

> **Ross:** *I’ll tell you what Mon, I’ll give you the first box [of cookies] for free.*
>
> **Monica:** [reaches for the box, then looks at it with terror] *OH GOD!!! I gotta GO!!* [runs out]

- She openly acknowledges that she has a *problem* with food and overeating:

> **Monica:** *The fat girl inside of me really wants to go. I owe her this. I never let her eat.*

---

Out of universe, although she [consistently denies it](http://www.contactmusic.com/courteney-cox/news/cox-regrets-skinny-past_1020634)...

> I did not have anorexia, but they [the press] kept writing about it.

...the harsh reality is that maintaining a size-zero physique for nearly a decade is invariably achieved through a regimen of constant exercise, food denial and cocaine.

Comment: Where is that from:Her weight borders on anorexically thin, something at least one character acknowledges.
Laura: I'm good. Wow, you lost a lot of weight! You look almost anorexic. Wait that didn't come out right. You, you look great.

Monica: Well thank you.

Comment: @Richard That's fanfic. Rachel doesn't have a sister called Laura.

Comment: This [real :P] quote might have some relevance, though, from episode 4x02: "The fat girl inside of me really wants to go [out with a boy she had a crush on in highschool]. I owe her this. **I never let her eat.**"